# Station Stop Failed?

Tags: train-simulator-2013

Somebody thought it would be funny to recommend this game to me, so I've played it for several hours during which time I have universally failed at everything it has thrown at me. During a typical journey to London Victoria station I received the message "Station Stop Failed" at each stop without fail, even though I arrived at the station, loaded/unloaded, saw virtual people getting on and off my train before setting off to the next stop.

Does this game hate me or am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather unintuitively, you get the 'Station Stop Failed' message when you either;

- Do not stop at a station you were supposed to stop at
- Arrive *late* to a station you were supposed to stop at, even if you successfully stop
- Stop in a way that all of the cars are not aligned with the platform, thus not loading/unloading those cars

For more information on the current status of the journey you're making you can press <kbd>F1</kbd> to see an overview of the stops you've made and the stops you're scheduled to make. Any of these stops that have a X instead of a tick have failed, and will reflect negatively in your end-of-journey score.